# Add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to variable before adding to database column

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, timestamp

How can I add a timestamp directly before the string I am adding to a database column. See below as to what I am trying to accomplish.

```
UPDATE My_TABLE
SET Admin_Notes = isNull(Admin_Notes,'') + CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.adminNotes#">
WHERE my_id = '5'
```

So I am adding to the current value of the field but before that I want to add a TimeStamp.

Comment: is your question how to get the time from the current_timestamp ? CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ? otherwise what you are doing looks fine to me

Comment: My question is how to add a timestamp before the string in adminnotes. When I go back and view the contents Admin_Notes before each "adminNotes" entry there will be a timestamp.

Comment: UPDATE My_TABLE
SET Admin_Notes = CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + isNull(Admin_Notes,'')

Comment: @Denoteone - Side note, be careful with concatenation. Implicit conversion can cause some unexpected things can happen. Also, you really need to start using  cfsqltypes on your all query parameters, for several reasons.  Your other thread mentioned that column is type `nvarchar(max)`.  If you omit the cfsqltype, there is a good chance any unicode text in that value will be garbled, possibly truncated as well. So if storing unicode characters is important, which the field type suggests it is) you *must* use the proper cfsqltype.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetimeformat(now(),'mask of your choice')` to cast the current date and time to a string.  You could probably do something similar with a database function.  The details depend on the database engine, which you didn't specify.

A better approach would be to add a LastUpdatedWhen field to the table and keep the date and time separate from the Admin_Notes.

Comment: I agree with keeping them seperate and I have setup another "Actions" table but this is for testing and will be removed at some point it just makes it quicker to review. Plus I had never done it before so I figured I would ask and learn.